# Use browsers back button after changing html content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, back-button

I am changing the html content of a div using jQuery on clicking a link.

```
<a href="#1" class="navclick" data-content="1">1</a>
<a href="#2" class="navclick" data-content="2">2</a>
<a href="#3" class="navclick" data-content="3">3</a>
```

So on click my jQuery code changes the html content.
Is there any way to make the browsers back button working again and change the content on clicking it? It does change the url but of course it is not changing the content back from f.e. #3 to #1 when i click the back button.

The libs I have found so far are out of date. What is the best way to do it at the moment?

Thanks!

### Edit:

This is how i load the content in the content div:

```
$('#content').hide().load($content+".html" , function(){
        $('#content').fadeIn('slow');
        var stateObj = { foo: $content };
        history.pushState(stateObj, $content, $content+".html");
        console.log(history);
    });
```

Comment: Yes, use `pushState` and `popState`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Answer (score 0):

Yes there sure is. Once you change your html content do a pushstate.

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

Now this will push bar.html to your URL so when you click back it wont go away from the current site but "Just" go back in history.

You can catch the click on back button like so:

```
$(window).on("popstate", function(e) {
  alert("Pressed back or forward");
});
```

Note that popstate fires on both backwards and forward click. so you need a way to check if user clicks backwards. But i will leave that up to you ;-)

Comment: Hi, thanks already. I have edited my first post and now also show how I load the content in the Div. Is this how you meant?